# Meteor js aggregate and publish

Tags: mongodb, cursor, aggregate, publish-subscribe, meteor-blaze

I want to inner join with users and reservations collection which reservation.userId = users._id 
in meteor.js.
I want to publish my reservations collection with userObj from users collection
So I used aggregate,

```
Meteor.publish("Reservations", function() {
var options = {
    allowDiskUse: true
};

var pipeline = [
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            reservations: "$$ROOT"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            localField: "reservations.userId",
            from: "users",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "users"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
            path: "$users",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "reservations._id": "$reservations._id",
            "reservations.placeId": "$reservations.placeId",
            "reservations.userId": "$reservations.userId",
            "reservations.date": "$reservations.date",
            "users._id": "$users._id",
            "users.profile": "$users.profile",
            _id: 0
        }
    }
];
 return Reservations.aggregate(pipeline, options);
  });
```

I am using aggregation (with meteorhacks:aggregate)

but i have some error like this,

```
I20191023-17:59:56.879(3)? Exception from sub Reservations id Yu9APaNsJKhNhnnGr Error: Publish function can only return a Cursor or an array of Cursors
I20191023-17:59:56.880(3)?     at Subscription._publishHandlerResult (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1132:18)
I20191023-17:59:56.882(3)?     at Subscription._runHandler (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1063:10)
I20191023-17:59:56.882(3)?     at Session._startSubscription (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:860:9)
I20191023-17:59:56.884(3)?     at Session.sub (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:625:12)
```

I used jcbernack:reactive-aggregate package but still doesnt work.

I need some help how would I use the aggregation with publish?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.toArray` to the end of line like so:

```
Reservations.aggregate(pipeline, options).toArray();
```

A side tip, It's better to use `sakulstra:aggregate` since it's a maintained fork of `meteorhacks:aggregate`.

https://github.com/sakulstra/meteor-aggregate

Answer (score 0):

When add `.toArray` I get this error:

```
I20191025-22:31:31.463(3)? Exception from sub Reservations id Af7Hs2WXjmmcErenc TypeError: Reservations.aggregate(...).toArray is not a function
I20191025-22:31:31.464(3)?     at Subscription._handler (server/reservation.js:41:12)
I20191025-22:31:31.464(3)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1771:12)
I20191025-22:31:31.464(3)?     at DDP._CurrentPublicationInvocation.withValue (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1046:15)
I20191025-22:31:31.465(3)?     at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (packages\meteor.js:1234:12)
I20191025-22:31:31.466(3)?     at Subscription._runHandler (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1044:51)
I20191025-22:31:31.466(3)?     at Session._startSubscription (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:860:9)
I20191025-22:31:31.466(3)?     at Session.sub (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:625:12)
I20191025-22:31:31.467(3)?     at packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:559:43
```

But I've tried:

```
 Reservations.aggregate(pipeline, options).forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc);
 });
```

I got my results but still i cant return this result.